# why typescript's empty object type doesn't mean an empty object without any properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface Person { name: string };

let person : Person = { name: "John Smith" };

let empt: {} = person;
```

I don't really understand the idea why typescript allow the above code to be compiled, isn't that `{}` means it doesn't contain any properties, but `Person` has one property `name`, `{}` obviously doesn't contain a property name called `name`,  how `Person` type can be assignable to an empty type?

Comment: See [ms/TS#44874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44874) and the question(s) linked above

Comment: `{}` is an object type without properties which (or: whose type) you care about.